# How to Edit the character motor script to enable slide on tagged objects rather than it is greater than slope limit?

Tags: character, unity-game-engine, slide

I am working on a 2.5D platforming game on Unity3D and I need my character to slide on tagged objects rather than being over the slope limit. I am using the character motor and FPS input scripts. 
 I have found the line that enables the slide and it is as follows:

```
function TooSteep () {
    return (groundNormal.y <= Mathf.Cos(controller.slopeLimit * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
}
```

This condition is clearly for over the slope limit, how would I be able to edit this function to return true if the game object the character is on is tagged by "Slide" for example.
Any help is appreciated thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a new boolean field to the charactermotor script and throw in an "or" in the if statement that checks if the player is grounded *and* if the ground is too steep, so it looks like this:

```
if(grounded && (TooSteep() || someNewBool))
```

Then, attach a trigger box collider to the object (don't bother with tags on the other object), and attach a monobehaviour with the following function in it:

```
function OnTriggerEnter(other:Collider) 
{
    if(other.tag.Equals("Player"))//Replace "Player" with the tag you marked the player with.
    {
         other.GetComponent(CharacterMotor).someNewBool = true;// The new bool you added to the charactermotor script
    } 
}
```

and another function that looks like this:

```
function OnTriggerExit(other:Collider) 
{
    if(other.tag.Equals("Player"))
    {
         other.GetComponent(CharacterMotor).someNewBool = false;
    } 
}
```